# Why my OPAL application doesn't link?

Tags: c++, voip, opalvoip

I use [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/) library in my application (Visual C++ 2008 Express), I built static version of ptlib and opal, a sopied ptlibs.lib and opals.lib to my project's lib folder. I also copied ptlib's and opal's include directiores to my app's folder. I added lib files to a linker configuration and include dir's to project configuration.

It compiles but doesn'tlink. Why? Is it a bug in OPAL ?

------ Build started: Project: infomat, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
MyOpalManager.cpp
Linking...
Searching libraries
    Searching d:\prj\voip\ptlib\Lib\ptlibs.lib:
    Searching d:\prj\voip\opal\lib\opals.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\winspool.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\shell32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\ole32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\odbc32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\MSVCRTD.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\MSVCRT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\quartz.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\strmiids.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\vfw32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\winmm.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\mpr.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\iphlpapi.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\dnsapi.lib:

Finished searching libraries
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use 
/NODEFAULTLIB:library

**MyOpalManager.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void * __cdecl PMemoryHeap::Allocate(unsigned int,char const *,int,char const *)" (?Allocate@PMemoryHeap@@SAPAXIPBDH0@Z) referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl H323EndPoint::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2H323EndPoint@@SAPAXI@Z)
MyOpalManager.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl PMemoryHeap::Deallocate(void *,char const *)" (?Deallocate@PMemoryHeap@@SAXPAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl H323EndPoint::operator delete(void *)" (??3H323EndPoint@@SAXPAX@Z)
MyOpalPCSSEndPoint.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl PMemoryHeap::Deallocate(void *,char const *)" (?Deallocate@PMemoryHeap@@SAXPAXPBD@Z)
d:\prj\voip\infomat\Debug\infomat.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals**
Build log was saved at "file://d:\prj\voip\infomat\infomat\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
infomat - 4 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0):

why not create your project in the same solution as ptlib or opal? It makes sense that , configurations are not required then.